# prevent html2pdf from considering head style

Tags: javascript, html, html2pdf

I am using below code to generate pdf using html2pdf

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.2/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script>
<style>
#content {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>This is some HTML content.</p>
</div>
<button id="download-button">Download PDF</button>
<script>
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    
    var options = {
        margin: [10, 10, 10, 10],
        filename: 'output.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 4 },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
        pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all' }
    };
    
    document.getElementById("download-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        html2pdf().set(options).from(content).save();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

This generate pdf with font color red, how can I prevent this, so it should not use any style or css that is added in head section.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new element with the same content, which will not include any style, or you can add your style to the new element:

```
const myContent = document.createElement('div');
myContent.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;
// set your styles..
myContent.style.cssText = 'color:green;';
html2pdf().set(options).from(myContent).save();
```

**EDIT**

To *exclude* a specific stylesheet is impossible without rendering the whole page with excluded styles.

To do so:

- clone the whole page
- exclude specific stylesheet
- render the cloned page in an iframe
- get pdf content element inside an iframe
- get its styles
- create a new element and apply content's styles and content
- print it

Here, the resulting PDF should ignore `color: red !important;` and apply `color: green;` instead:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.2/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script>
    <style>
    #content {
        color: red !important;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
    #content {
        color: green;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is some HTML content.</p>
    </div>
    <button id="download-button">Download PDF</button>
    <script>
      var options = {
        margin: [10, 10, 10, 10],
        filename: 'output.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 4 },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
        pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all' }
    };

  document.getElementById("download-button").addEventListener("click", function() {


      // copy the page
      const docCopy = document.cloneNode(true);

      // disable whatever style
      docCopy.querySelector('head style').remove();


      // get the print content
      const content = docCopy.getElementById("content");

      // render it inside an iframe
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      const html = docCopy.documentElement.innerHTML;
      iframe.style.cssText = 'position:absolute; top: -9999999px;'
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
      iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
      iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

      // now get its css styles
      const contentComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('content'));

      // create and apply css and content it the new element
      const pdfContent = docCopy.createElement('div');

      pdfContent.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;


      [...contentComputedStyle].forEach(prop => pdfContent.style.setProperty(prop, contentComputedStyle.getPropertyValue(prop), contentComputedStyle.getPropertyPriority(prop)));

      // print the new element
      html2pdf().set(options).from(pdfContent).save();

  });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: this will not work if you have css for div and for other elements.

Comment: try the updated code. it's quite difficult, because it requires re-rendering the whole page without the specific style. It's a strange use case, the best way would be my initial suggestion, IMHO